# How to switch a monitor on a laptop as if the monitor was connected to another computer?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, desktop-computer

I just got a laptop to bring into work, but I also want to use it at home, by connecting it to my home desktop computer as if the monitor on the laptop as if the laptop screen was another screen connected to the computer. For instance, I can drag a window to the laptop screen.

A related question (which also has a linked question) is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/789691/sharing-2-monitors-between-2-computers-in-different-configurations), but I'm not sure if that will do what I want.

I'm not sure if using a KVM switch will allow me to do what I want. Team Viewer would allow me to remotely control the laptop via the desktop, or vice versa, but it is sluggish, not very secure, and isn't quite the same as the laptop being like another desktop connected monitor. Mouse Without Borders allows me to share a mouse and keyboard between two computers, but it won't allow me to have the full functionality of the laptop screen being like another monitor connected to the desktop.

Both computers have Windows 10 v. 1703 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There is no way to transparently drag a Window or similar from one machine to the other on Windows. Your setup would require to actually attach the notebook screen as another display.